# Incorrect array shape

Tags: python

Just wanted to ask quickly how I would reshape my list which prints the shape as (50, 25, 3) to a shape of just (50, 25). Im a little confused as to where the 3 is actually coming from to be honest and I have to reference the sizes for a check. So I need them to match up even if I have to change the implementation.

One list:

```
def templates():
    templatesArray = [[],[],[],[],[]]
    counter = 0



    for dirs in os.listdir(args["templates"]):
        pathToFiles = args["templates"] + "/" + dirs + "/*.jpg"

        for imagePaths in glob.glob(pathToFiles):
            #print(imagePaths)
            tempCard = cv2.imread(imagePaths)
            templatesArray[counter].append(tempCard)
        counter += 1
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    return templatesArray
```

Other list

```
def pointsOfIntrest(img):
    intrestArray = [[], [], [], [], []]

    yStart = 335   ####Position of FlopOne Cards Upper Left Corner
    xStart = 438
    flopOne = img[yStart:yStart + 50, xStart:xStart + 25]
    flopOne = cv2.cvtColor(flopOne, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    flopOne = auto_canny(flopOne)
    intrestArray[FLOP_ONE].append(flopOne)



    xStart = 530
    flopTwo = img[yStart:yStart + 50, xStart:xStart + 25]
    flopTwo = cv2.cvtColor(flopTwo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    flopTwo = auto_canny(flopTwo)
    intrestArray[FLOP_TWO].append(flopTwo)



    xStart = 621
    flopThree = img[yStart:yStart + 50, xStart:xStart + 25]
    flopThree = cv2.cvtColor(flopThree, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    flopThree = auto_canny(flopThree)
    intrestArray[FLOP_THREE].append(flopThree)


    xStart = 711
    turn = img[yStart:yStart + 50, xStart:xStart + 25]
    turn = cv2.cvtColor(turn, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    turn = auto_canny(turn)
    intrestArray[TURN].append(turn)


    xStart = 801
    river = img[yStart:yStart + 50, xStart:xStart + 25]
    river = cv2.cvtColor(river, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    river = auto_canny(river)
    intrestArray[RIVER].append(river)
```

I know this could have been implemented better. Please ask if my code makes no sense.
The Following is the output when I print the shapes.

C:\Users\Turtle\PycharmProjects\MakeGood>python main.py --templates CardRawData --images Images

('50', '25')

('50', '25', '3')

A bit hacky and long but this is how I printed the shape.

```
print(str(pointsToCompare[FLOP_ONE][0].shape[0]),str(pointsToCompare[FLOP_TWO][0].shape[1]))
print(str(boardCards[FLOP_ONE][element].shape[0]), str(boardCards[FLOP_ONE][element].shape[1]),str(boardCards[FLOP_ONE][element].shape[2]))
```

Change printing method to a better suggestion by EVERT

```
print(str(pointsToCompare[FLOP_ONE][0].shape))
print(str(boardCards[FLOP_ONE][element].shape))
```

Comment: sorry I will edit

Comment: Since this is OpenCV, I wonder if those are just the RGB values, which would fully explain the size of the extra dimension.

Comment: the first two values are height and width...the 3 I have no idea

Comment: im not even sure where its getting set so I can extend the other list

Comment: Well, what I said: you're using `imread` somewhere, it may read an RGB triple. Look up the API documentaiton.

Comment: element will send out of bounds...this is incorrect sorry

Comment: look im looking for help not a disection of my code it prints what it prints and how i got there is not important. the error came from an output from a comparison

Comment: Just because you have no idea what the problem is doesnt mean it isnt clear....

Comment: the print method doesnt have anything to do with it...I explained that the error came from and output from comparision the sizes are different...if you dont know what the problem is fine...however im sure there will be someone that does

Comment: I have edited to include your suggestion thank you

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread : "`cv2.imread`: flags: >0 Return a 3-channel color image." (default flag = 1).

Comment: AAHHHHH!!! Your onto something you know

Comment: Lol that simple changed flag to -1...bosh there the same size...Please put as answer so I can add

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer to this question was pointed out rightly by Evert.
The array was reading in an RGB value for the 3rd dimension because I didnt set the flag correctly on imread.

Before:

```
tempCard = cv2.imread(imagePaths)
```

After:

```
tempCard = cv2.imread(imagePaths, -1)
```

I take no credit for this it was Evert that patiently sorted out for me. Thanks very much

The link to the documentation in regards to this is [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html?highlight=imread#cv2.imread)
, my problem is referred to in the imread parameters section referencing the flags. Hope this helps.

Thanks again.

Comment: You can still accept your own answer as being solved, to complete things. I also suggest to add a link to the relevant documentation, so that people can look up the full meaning of that flag (even better: link the documentation, *and* quote the relevant section from the documentation).